# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingbottom' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

There was a problem in the relative layout "paddingbottom" so please tell me how to resolve it

```
<textview android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world">

<imageview android:id="@+id/imageView_image" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margintop="64dp" android:layout_torightof="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<button android:id="@+id/button_insert" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_image" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margintop="45dp" android:layout_torightof="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Insert In DB">

</button><button android:id="@+id/button_retrieve" android:layout_alignleft="@+id/button_insert" android:layout_below="@+id/button_insert" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margintop="56dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Retrieve from DB">
```

Comment: it is `android:paddingBottom` with the capital `B`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Tag

```
android:paddingBottom="your_value_in_dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:--->

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_insert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Insert In DB" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_retrieve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/button_insert"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_insert"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:text="Retrieve from DB" />
```